# Qt OS 10.6 build not running on OS 10.5 and less

Tags: macos, qt, compatibility

This issue has been queried twice before by separate people, but there have been no answers.

So, I'm posting, again:

Building Qt4.7 on 10.6.6, XCode 3.2.5, g++-4.2 with the flag '-mmacosx-version-min=10.4', which I'm presuming is taking care of the dirty work, underneath.

When I bring it over to 10.5, it crashes right out of the box with this:

```
<... process identification info removed ...>

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: __ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_i
  Referenced from: /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

Has anyone come to a resolution on this?

Comment: Long shot - does the 10.5 machine has the 10.4 SDK and runtime stuff? Normally found here: /Developer/SDKs/  (assuming you install Xcode in /Developer, otherwise replace with the install path you used).

Comment: hmm.  not sure.  will look.

Partial solution: I switched to the g++ 4.0 compiler (4.2 default is stated as 'experimental' - makes for a lousy default...)

Anyway, that seems to have fixed it for 10.5.

Comment: Yes, I have the 10.4u sdk.  I get errors trying to build Qt against it, though.  See below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `-sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk` in your configure line when building Qt itself. The minimum version option is just to trigger some pre-processor macros to limit APIs to 10.4 level.

Note this may stop you from building 64-bit binaries. But I am not sure.

Comment: hmm.  I get compile errors with this.  Does Qt4.7 build with the 10.4 sdk?  I'm thinking maybe not...

Comment: According to the docs, 4.7 is supposed to support 10.4 and up.

Comment: You need to target Carbon to build for 10.4: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/developing-on-mac.html

Comment: I was under the impression specifying -universal (or -x86 -ppc) essentially *is* carbon, by inference.  Not so?  Can you target those architectures with Cocoa?

Hmm.  Try another rebuild, I guess....

Comment: Ok, that all worked.  So, the config commandline now looks like this:
*-sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -carbon -universal*, and the in the project: *CONFIG += carbon i386 ppc* and *QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.4*
<br/>
I don't mind telling any Nokia/Trolltech lurkers that this is less than obvious from the docs.

Comment: another gotcha: even if you specify macx-g++40, you'll still get the 4.2 compiler.  I had to actually move the macx-g++ dir out of mkspecs, and copy the macx-g++40 dir to macx-g++.  All works fine, now (I'm updating this late...)

Comment: DOH!!!  Never mind last.  Turns out I had an extra '-platform=macx-g++' in my config line, and that was over-riding the '-platform=macx-g++40'.  removed that, and the g++40 spec takes fine.

Yeesh!  Too many options...